# Device name in cognito tracking device

Tags: amazon-web-services, react-native, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

My react native app sends the application name while login with amplify  "react-app"
how do I change it on login?

Answer (score 0):

I found it
the device name comes from the User-Agent header in the request